# Register 1 mouseDragged event for multiple JPanels

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, mouseevent, mousemotionevent

I have a Main JPanel with two other JPanels on top of it (Panel A and Panel B) as illustrated in the following image:

[image]

I want to track the mouseDragged event on these JPanels, and at the moment to do that I am tracking it for all of the 3 JPanels as such:

```
mainPanel.addMouseMotionListener(new java.awt.event.MouseMotionAdapter() {
    public void mouseDragged(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {

    }
});

panelA.addMouseMotionListener(new java.awt.event.MouseMotionAdapter() {
    public void mouseDragged(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {

    }
});

panelB.addMouseMotionListener(new java.awt.event.MouseMotionAdapter() {
    public void mouseDragged(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {

    }
});
```

Is there a way to track the mouseDragged event for all 3 JPanels by registering just 1 listener instead of 3 as I have above? Thank you

Answer (score 3):

```
class MyMouseMotionListener implements MouseMotionListener{
    public void mouseDragged(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {

    }
}

...

MouseMotionListener myListener = new MyMouseMotionListener();

mainPanel.addMouseMotionListener(myListener);
panelA.addMouseMotionListener(myListener);
panelB.addMouseMotionListener(myListener);
```

Comment: i think that s/he wants to apply redispatch events to the parent, two three methods in swingutilities, sorry from cellphone...

Comment: This works as well, the events from all 3 panels will be registered by one listener.

Comment: nope, you got the question, I just want to see the other way too

Comment: @jadrijan: Jakub's shared instance apporach is better; [`GlassPaneDemo`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html#eg) is an example using `dispatchEvent()` .